# How to get current logged in user SID

Tags: c#, windows, security, microsoft-metro

How to get the current logged in user's SID in metro C#/XAML?

WindowsIdentity class no longer seems to be available. Do I need to do a WinRT component DLL of some sort to get this functionality?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you're trying to accomplish, user information (not the SID) is available via Windows.System.UserProfile.UserInformation class.

Comment: Looking for something that is unique and doesn't change over the lifetime of a windows user account.